# Why is $\frac{\int_{64}^{65}1.04^xdx}{\int_{24.5}^{25.5}1.04^xdx}=1.04^{39.5}\;?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am not sure whether these two things are exactly equal or only approximately equal. Wolfram says the difference is zero. I also would like to know why they are equal (or approximately)

$$\frac{\int_{64}^{65}1.04^xdx}{\int_{24.5}^{25.5}1.04^xdx}=1.04^{39.5}$$

Edit: I believe they are only approximately equal. The LHS is $\frac{1.04^{65}-1.04^{64}}{1.04^{25.5}-1.04^{24.5}}$. But why is that approximately equal to $1.04^{39.5}$ and why does wolfram give the difference as 0 instead of the actual difference.

Comment: Do you know what's $\int a^x dx$?

Comment: Yes. Look at the edit

Comment: $1.04^{65} - 1.04^{64} = 1.04^{39.5} (1.04^{25.5} - 1.04^{24.5})$.

Comment: Factorize $1.04^{39.5}$ in the numerator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1.04^{65}-1.04^{64}}{1.04^{25.5}-1.04^{24.5}}$$
is *exactly* equal to $1.04^{39.5}$. To give you a start, the numerator is $1.04^{64}(1.04 - 1)$; now try and calculate the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe they are only approximately equal

No it is exact.

This more general result is easy to prove :

$$\frac{\int_a^{a+\delta}c^xdx}{\int_b^{b+\delta}c^xdx}=c^{a-b}$$

It's the same process as @TonyK gave in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3699842/298172).